# HP x360 spectre immediately leaves suspend

Tags: suspend, 21.10

My daugthers HP x360 spectre has a problem when running Linux. When she closes the lid, it suspends, and shortly after it resumes, and then stays on in the bag.

I can do a "systemctl suspend", and it suspends. But if the lid is closed, then it starts again.

I can see this in the syslog

```
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4154.225957] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.120 seconds) done.
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4154.346805] OOM killer disabled.
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4154.346807] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4154.348767] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4154.642790] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4157.541371] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4158.703026] OOM killer enabled.
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4158.703031] Restarting tasks ...
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4158.707034] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4158.707812] done.
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4158.715306] pcieport 10000:e0:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 10000:e1:00.0
Feb 19 00:30:12 Spectre-x360-14 kernel: [ 4158.715324] nvme 10000:e1:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
```

It seems that this causes starts the problem: "ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked"

So my guess is that it has something to do with ACPI.

- I have tried to update the BIOS, but it claims to be latest.
- There is no ACPI settings in the BIOS.
- I have tried to add these to kernel command line pci=noaer pcie_ports=native.
- I have even tried to run "systemctl suspend" in crontab, which gave the same behaviour.

Anybody have an idea to what I can try next?

Ubuntu: 21.10

This is a brand new machine. She previously had an older x360 model, which worked fine, but a lot of IO has changed.

```
HP Spectre x360 Convertible
14-ea0xxx
Productnumber 4A6L5EA#UUW
```

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Hardware specifications?

Comment: Have you tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600528/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-the-hp-spectre-x360) suggestions?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3Asuspend+title%3Ax360