# Does an HP Proliant DL360 G9 is supported by Ubuntu (Any version)?

Tags: drivers, server, hard-drive, hp, raid

I would like to know if Ubuntu can be installed on a new server HP with this characteristics:

HP Part number: 755262-B21

Specifications:
HP ProLiant DL360p Gen9, Intel® Xeon® E5-2630v3 (2.4GHz/8-core/20MB/85W), 16GB (1x16GB), HP Embedded 1Gb Ethernet 4-port 331i Adapter, HP Flexible Smart Array P440ar/2GB (RAID 0, 1, 10, 5, 6), 8 SFF HDD Bays, Optional via Universal Media Bay, 2 Standard (1-FH/¾ L, 1-LP) PCIe 3.0,  (1) HP 500W Flex Slot Platinum Power Supply, 5 Standard hot plug fans, redundant, iLO Management (standard), Intelligent Provisioning (standard).

Thanks in advance

Victor David Nasser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *but only with the Smart Array disabled*. According to the **Ubuntu Hardware Certification Program**:

## The HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9 rack mount chassis with the components described below has been awarded the status of certified for Ubuntu.

---

## Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

This system was tested with 16.04 LTS, running the 4.4.0-15.31 kernel.

#### Certification notes

HP Dynamic Smart Array

System is certified with Dynamic Smart Array disabled.

To disable Dynamic Smart Array:

- Press F9 to boot into RBSU
- Navigate to System Options -> HP Dynamic Smart Array B320i and select disable
- Go to System options -> SATA Controller options and select Legacy SATA or AHCI
- Reboot the machine and now you will be able to install the OS.

#### Pre-Release Testing

This system was tested with a Pre-Release version of Ubuntu.

This certification is considered valid only for 60 days after this Ubuntu Release and must be re-tested with the GA release of Ubuntu to be considered permanently certified.

BIOS

- HP: P89 (UEFI)

---

## Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit

This system was tested with 14.04 LTS, running the 3.13.0-35.62 kernel.

#### Certification notes

HP ILO and MAAS

- ILO firmware version 2.30 will not work with MAAS. To use this system in a MAAS environment you will need to update to the latest ILO firmware (greater than version 2.30).
- If you are using ILO 2.20 or older, you are not affected by this issue. Please refer to HP for more information on updating ILO firmware.

BIOS

- HP: P89 (UEFI)

---

This information can be viewed at http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201409-15509/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will take in mind the information, so have no problems when installing the operating system. I really appreciate your help. Kind regards

Comment: I'm happy to help! If you found this answer helpful, feel free to mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the gray check-mark next to it.