# Choosing a motherboard for a ubuntu build

Tags: drivers, kernel, compatibility

I'm planning my first computer build. Because I love programming I decided to go with linux for a unix like operating system. I've spent hours reading about components. My first plans for a system build was a gaming rig and I started to like the company gigabyte. The motherboard I'm planning on using for this linux build is the gigabyte GA-H170-HD3.

My question is will it work with linux? I started hesitating when I looked for linux drivers for the motherboard, but didn't find any. I went around the internet for a bit and saw a person talk about drivers got programmed into the linux kernel and ubuntu kernel directly. Is this true? Is "linux compatibility" nothing really to worry about? Or if it is, where should I look for linux compatible components?

Many questions that needs to be answered. Please explain for me, I really do want to know what I should do to succeed with this build.

PS. I'm sorry if the english isn't the best, it's my second language,

Comment: Almost all motherboards use components that work with generic drivers included in the Linux kernel in Ubuntu. You probably do not have to worry about any incompatibilities. But, you should check your graphics card and wireless card for compatibility - AMD Radeon graphics cards have pretty bad performance in Ubuntu but Nvidia GTX graphics cards work very well. I'm leaving a comment instead of an answer since I haven't thoroughly checked the motherboard's specs but I'm extremely confident that it will work fine.

Comment: The gpu isn't the the most important in my build, but it of course need to work. I'm going with nvidia, but I have to check for a compatible wireless card. By the way, thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm seeing on the [GA-H170M-HD3 DDR3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5557#sp) description is:

"Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors, please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website."

which doesn't means that linux is not supported. It should be fine - It will depends on the general configuration of the machine... :)

As a general rule, if the drivers are free you can check on the [Xorg](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/Projects/Drivers/) website for the list of all supported cards, otherwise you can check directly on the manufacturers' sites.

Ubuntu has also a list of certified component that you can check on the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/) website.

Another good list is displayed on [Linux-driver](http://linux-drivers.org/).

Hope this help!

Comment: He probably is going to want the version that uses DDR4. It's the newer standard. I didn't even know the motherboards with LGA1151 sockets could support DDR3.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going for the ddr4 version, but I'll keep the tips about checking for supported components, thanks!

Comment: I read a post on ubuntuforum about the DDR4 version saying that it worked without any problem...