# XPS 13 - With external screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, xps

I'm searching for a good linux laptop. I found the Dell XPS 13 on ubuntu. I want to use it for working (I'm a IT developper). I want to use it at work with 2 dual external screens (maybe with an external keyboard and mouse).

The exact model is 93611, with Intel® HD 620 graphic card.
Here the link : http://www.dell.com/ch/p/xps-13-9360-laptop/pd?oc=cnx93611&l=fr&s=dhs

- Someone have a feedback on this ?
- Is the laptop working well with 2 dual screens ?
- Is there a good 'docker station' to buy ?

Thank you

Comment: What you probably need to look into is whether the USB-C adapter(s) work with Ubuntu and multiple displays - but if you are getting the machine with Ubuntu pre-installed then I guess it should work. The GPU is part of the CPU and according to the spec should support 3 displays http://ark.intel.com/products/95451/Intel-Core-i7-7500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz-?q=i7-7500U . There should be something in the manual on what the thunderbolt controller chip supports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware)

Comment: If you're buying a complete computer with Ubuntu pre-installed it should work out of the box. Otherwise contact the seller and request a repair, replacement, or return.