# Reports of Ubuntu working smoothly on HP Spectre X360 -- will it work on Spectre 13?

Tags: hp, compatibility

I'm thinking of purchasing a HP Spectre 13 (either Skylake or Kaby Lake) but I need to know that it'll run Ubuntu nicely (dual boot).  I've seen many people with it working on their X360s, is it safe to assume it will work on the non-touchscreen models?  Anyone personally have it working on their Spectre 13s (Skylake/Kaby Lake)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spectre 13 has well above the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu of any version (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) so the main thing you would want to worry about is your gpu.

However, the HP Spectre 13 has Intel HD Graphics, which I am also flawlessly using right now with Kubuntu 16.10 on my own Toshiba Laptop.

Most HP computers have an option to choose boot device, and I would think that this one is no exception.

Ubuntu also has the option to install alongside, so once Windows 10 is installed, just install ubuntu and the GRUB will allow you to choose which os to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on initial 'not so good' experience, I suggest some caution in attempts to create a dual-boot system using the Windows 10 as installed and adding Ubuntu.  The Spectre comes with a new type of bios which has a secure boot mode by default.  In addition the partition layout is a bit different from legacy systems most of us are familiar with and so the steps required to shrink the windows 10 partition and install Ubuntu are different from the past.  I know because I screwed it up and now will have to reinstall windows 10 and start over again.  I did install Ubuntu 16.04 on the entire drive to verify that it works and it does, everything including sound, as well as all of my applications.

So when the HP provided (very kindly) usb recovery drive shows up, I'll reinstall windows 10 and then CAREFULLY follow the necessary steps to correctly create a dual boot installation. I'll post references to the entire process when I've succeeded late next week.

**Note**: I should add that had I been prudent enough to make a recovery usb before attempting the dual boot installation, I probably wouldn't have needed for HP to send me their USB.

Comment: I should add that had I been prudent enough to make a recovery usb before attempting the dual boot installation, I probably wouldn't have needed for HP to send me their USB.