# Dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 Dell 7560

Tags: dual-boot, dell, windows-10

I have recently bought Dell 7560 (7000) series. It has come with Windows 10. I want to add ubuntu as second operating system. If anyone has tried installing ubuntu with Windows 10 in the same system, can you please tell me what problems did you face and what should I keep in mind except taking backup of the system. Also, which version of ubuntu is supported? I know there are some many answers related to this but I need answers related to this Dell 7560 system. I would like to know compatibility issues, specifically.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I want to know compatibility issues specifically for Dell 7560

Comment: @DavidFoerster:  [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware) This question is about different hardware specifications, Here I want to know about dell 7560.

Comment: You missed the point which is that hardware compatibility questions are usually too broad for the Q&A format of AksUbuntu – especially if you're in possession of the hardware in question and can just use a live DVD/USB of Ubuntu and test the compatibility yourself. Take a look at the answers of the linked question and you'll see that they're not specific to the hardware of the question author.

Comment: Okay @DavidFoerster. I understand your point. I will take care of it next time. I just want to know if someone has gone through any trouble related to my type of device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Seems like it's compatible**

The fastest and most assured way to check if you're laptop (or desktop) is compatible is to see the certified hardware list published by Ubuntu

[Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/)

[Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 7560](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201606-22349/)

The version that's officially supported on the page above in 16.04 LTS, but it's no harm to check out 17.04 (latest) via *Try ubuntu Before installing* session, keep in mind that 17.04 supports *kaby-lake* processors and your laptop has *Kaby-lake* processor

---

But remember that this is an official list maintained and published by canonical and ubuntu, if you're device isn't in the list that doesn't mean that it's completely unsupported

Comment: @mayankmittal you're always welcome, and welcome to *askubuntu*