# User experience of Ubuntu 17.04 on Dell Inspiron 7560

Tags: dell

I am planning to buy a Dell Inspiron 7560 (kaby lake) which comes with Windows 10 pre-installed. 
I have no preference in using Windows on my laptop Hence thinking about installing Ubuntu on it. I see that this model is already certified by Ubuntu https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201606-22349/

However, the page also says that "Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well, though Canonical and computer manufacturers will try to certify the system with future standard releases of Ubuntu.
"

I also see some of the users asked the same question in the past but would like to hear from anybody who has actually installed Ubuntu on this model and what problems do we need to expect? or it runs smooth.

[Dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 Dell 7560](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908666/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-dell-7560)

Answer (score 3):

I have this exact model, but I have already bought it with Ubuntu 16.04LTS preinstalled. I have formatted it and installed Kubuntu 17.04.

There were some difficulties in partitioning; I had to do it manually using KDE Partition Manager, because I wanted to keep the original partitions and just make a big one for Kubuntu. When I decide to format it again, I will not do this; I'll just let the system erase all and make its own partition scheme.

Everything is running just fine, no problems. I am a Brazilian user, and my DELL came with an ABNT2 type keyboard. Working just fine.