# What is requirment for linux

Tags: laptop

Please help me .
I am interested to learn linux.
Can I install linux in any Laptop ❔
My laptop asus x556u
Am I able to install linux ?

Comment: This question is far too broad. Are you able to at least narrow down what particular OS/flavour of Linux you're looking to install? Based on the specifications available on the internet for that model, it should be able to support most common distributions (Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS etc), but the specifics regarding fully working drivers for all the machine utilities are not so readily available.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu if your Laptop meets the following requirements: 
    700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better), 512 MiB RAM (system memory), 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach), VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution, Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can install gnu / linux on that pc, I recommend that you install ubuntu 
since it is the easiest distribution to use if you come from windows, I advise that when you install the so on your computer you do it manually, to Which configures the partitions in a way that suits your computer better. Any questions you have will be happy to solve it.

regards